# How hook the multitask on iOS 12

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, cydia, tweak

**Hi, I'm create a tweak tu custom multitask on iOS but don't find the good header.**

> My code :

```
%hook SBMainSwitcherViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
%orig;
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController 

alertControllerWithTitle:@"AppSwitcher" message:@"Clear cache"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Thank God !"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                        }];
   [alert addAction:yesButton];
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

%end
```

**It's doesn't work...**

**I just want at this time to show a UIAlert when multitask is activate.**

**Thx for help**

Comment: Does jailbreak work at all on iOS12? Any links?

Comment: There is Unc0ver for iOS 12